# Abnormally large drivers/modules directories when building a custom kernel on Ubuntu 18.04 / 20.04

Tags: build, compilation, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I'm currently tiptoeing into custom kernel building.

I first started on a VM in VirtualBox, installing a fresh distribution of Ubuntu Server 20.04.

I followed the following procedure:

```sh
# getting the archive
cd ~/src/linux/
wget https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/linux-5.4.91.tar.xz
tar -xf linux-5.4.91.tar.xz 
cd linux-5.4.91/

# getting the config of the kernel currently running
cp -v /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config

# adapting the config to the target kernel, selecting the default for everything
make oldconfig

# adding manually a suffix to the kernel name: "-tony"
make menuconfig

# building and installing modules & image
time make -j $(nproc)
sudo make modules_install
sudo make install
```

Everything goes fine, although the build takes a bit longer than expected (~30 minutes on a 6-core AMD Ryzen 5 3600 6-Core Processor, with 32 GB of RAM; I assigned 6 CPUs over the 12 available to the VM).

However, when I check the size of the source directory, now containing the object files of everything built, the size of the `drivers` directory bothers me:

```sh
user@vm:~/src/linux/linux-5.4.91$ du -hd 1
1.3G    ./fs
544K    ./certs
34M ./block
128K    ./usr
41M ./tools
208K    ./LICENSES
58M ./security
48M ./Documentation
3.4M    ./init
58M ./include
895M    ./sound
73M ./lib
5.1M    ./ipc
95M ./crypto
2.0G    ./net
2.2M    ./samples
446M    ./arch
5.2M    ./scripts
195M    ./.git
4.8M    ./virt
142M    ./kernel
56M ./mm
13G ./drivers
20G .
```

13 GB looks like a lot.
When I look at the installed files, the modules also looks very big (5.6G):

```sh
root@vm:/# find -name '*5.4.91*' | xargs du -hs
20G ./home/user/src/linux/linux-5.4.91
105M    ./home/user/src/linux/linux-5.4.91.tar.xz
5.6G    ./usr/lib/modules/5.4.91-tony+
4.0K    ./var/lib/initramfs-tools/5.4.91-tony+
912M    ./boot/initrd.img-5.4.91-tony+
232K    ./boot/config-5.4.91-tony+
12M ./boot/vmlinuz-5.4.91-tony+
4.5M    ./boot/System.map-5.4.91-tony+
```

Especially when I compare with the vanilla kernel installed with the distribution:

```sh
root@vm:/# find -name '*5.4.0-62*' | xargs du -hs
...
262M    ./usr/lib/modules/5.4.0-62-generic
4.0K    ./usr/lib/modprobe.d/blacklist_linux_5.4.0-62-generic.conf
4.0K    ./var/lib/initramfs-tools/5.4.0-62-generic
...
12M ./boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-62-generic
79M ./boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-62-generic
236K    ./boot/config-5.4.0-62-generic
4.6M    ./boot/System.map-5.4.0-62-generic
```

262M vs 5.6G seems like a lot of difference, taken into account that I took the same config file (the `cp -v /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config` command).

I also reproduced the same results on Ubuntu Server 18.04.
Moreover, I tried on my host directly (no VM) with again the same results.

I am obviously missing something here, but I cannot find what:

- should I strip the kernel / the modules from unused symbols?
- is there a configuration that is missing somewhere ?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Ubuntu kernel configs have `CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y`. I haven't looked at their kernel package build scripts to see how they split out the debugging symbols.

Comment: ```bash
user@vm:/usr/lib/modules$ du -hs *
262M    5.4.0-62-generic
254M    5.4.91-tony+
```

Way better once I removed CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO, thanks!
Now I'm wondering why the configuration of shipped Ubuntu kernel has it set to yes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling CONFIG_SLUB_DEBUG, CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO and CONFIG_DEBUG_MISC in the kernel configuration resulted in reasonable build performance:

```sh
real    22m19.559s                                                                                   
user    119m17.273s                                                                                  
sys     12m15.424s
```

And the following size for the modules:

```sh
root@vm:/usr/lib/modules# du -hs *
261M    5.10.10-stripped+
262M    5.4.0-64-generic
```

Which is even better than the shipped kernel :) (notice I updated the kernel source, but it doesn't change the result if using the same kernel).

Apparently, one can also use `make modules_install INSTALL_MOD_STRIP=1` to strip the modules when they are built with debug symbols, reducing the size without having to change the build options.

Installing with that option on the already-stripped kernel & modules as described above resulted in the following size:

```sh
user@vm:/usr/lib/modules$ du -hs *
260M    5.10.10-stripped+
262M    5.4.0-64-generic
```

We effectively gain one more megabyte from this additionnal stripping.